# How to count the number of instances of two cells matching but not being blank in two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to formulate a football league table in Google Sheets, having laid out all the fixtures in a separate sheet, and am trying to calculate the number of draws each team has. I've already got formulas for wins and losses, which work without a hitch, but draws are significantly harder, because the same type of formula as I've used for wins and losses also counts the fixtures for which I have not yet filled in the result, i.e. fixtures which have not yet happened. This means that, for every match that has not been played, the league table adds 1 point to the two teams, which is something I want to avoid. Below, I'll list the 3 formulas I've tried already, and explain what they do and why they don't work:

1. `=SUMPRODUCT('My Predictions'!$J$2:$J$500=$B25,'My Predictions'!$K$2:$K$500='My Predictions'!$L$2:$L$500)`
   This is the original formula, the same as I've used for wins and losses, just having changed the operator symbol to =. It counts all the blank fixtures as well as the actual draws.
2. `=SUMPRODUCT(('My Predictions'!$M$2:$M$500=$B25)*AND(('My Predictions'!$L$2:$L$500='My Predictions'!$K$2:$K$500),('My Predictions'!$L$2:$L$500<>"")))`
   *(This the one for away fixtures, hence why the referenced cells are different)*
3. `=COUNTIF('My Predictions'!$J$2:$J$418,AND('My Predictions'!$K$2:$K$418='My Predictions'!$L$2:$L$418,'My Predictions'!$K$2:$K$418<>""))`
   Nos. 2 and 3 both have the same result, in that they return 0 draws, even if some teams have drawn a few games. I'm putting this down to these two formulas checking to see if the entire column is blank, as opposed to just the relevant cells, but I do not know this formula well enough to know if that is actually the issue.

If anyone could help me work out what formula could both count the number of actual draws, while also not counting blank fixtures, it'd be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new condition in the first one doesn't work? Similar to your second one

```
    =SUMPRODUCT('My Predictions'!$J$2:$J$500=$B25,
'My Predictions'!$K$2:$K$500='My Predictions'!$L$2:$L$500,
'My Predictions'!$K$2:$K$500<>"")
```

Comment: I'd forgotten you could have more than 2 arguments in a SUMPRODUCT. Thank you.